# Not getting added new item in exists state list variable in reactJS hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using ReactJs Hooks, I have two state array variable one containing list of items from that i am filtering by boolean value and want to add into another state array variable, i tried many ways not working working its only adding last item of the loop with only arr.Push()

- arr.concat()
- setlstRolePageMapping([...lstRolePageMapping,arr);
- arr.push()

---

```
const handleAdd = () => {

    let arr = [];  

    for (let data of lstPage) {

        if (data.Select) {               

            objRolePage.Flag = "INSERT" ;

            objRolePage.RoleId = 2 ;

            objRolePage.PageId = data.PageId;

            objRolePage.UpdatedBy = 775 ; 

            arr.push(objRolePage); 

        }  

     }

     console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));   

}
```

Following codes are not working

```
setlstRolePageMapping([...lstRolePageMapping, objRolePage] ); 

arr.concat(objRolePage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're reusing the same object for each loop run (`objRolePage`). Pushing it to the array does not make a copy of it so you end up pushing the same object which is then modified in the next loop run.

You may fix it by resetting `objRolePage` on each loop run, for example:

```js
let arr = [];  

for (let data of lstPage) {
    if (data.Select) {               
        const objRolePage = {
            Flag: 'INSERT',
            RoleId: 2,
            PageId: data.PageId,
            UpdatedBy: 775,
        };
        arr.push(objRolePage);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot its working fine, I applied the code on button click, when i click first time its showing empty arr in console.log,

Comment: when i click second time its appearing

Comment: if i display on page using   {JSON.stringify(lstRolePageMapping)} on first click its showing data

Comment: const handleAdd=()=>{
        let i=0;
        let arr = []; 
        for ( let data of lstPage) {
            if (data.Select) {               
                let obj ={ Flag:"INSERT", RoleId:2, PageId: data.PageId, UpdatedBy:755} ;
                  arr.push(obj);   
            }   
         }
         setlstRolePageMapping(arr);
         console.log(JSON.stringify(lstRolePageMapping)); 
    }

Comment: You should add this code to your question, it's unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Use ES for second array too (line 12)

```
1.    let arr = [];  
2.    for ( let data of lstPage) {
3.        if (data.Select) {               
4.            objRolePage.Flag = "INSERT" ;
5.            objRolePage.RoleId =2 ;
6.            objRolePage.PageId = data.PageId;
7.            objRolePage.UpdatedBy = 775 ; 
8.            arr.push(objRolePage); 
9.        }  
10.     }
11.    setlstRolePageMapping([...lstRolePageMapping,...arr]); // <=== new line
12.    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: [{"Flag":"INSERT","RoleId":2,"PageId":1005,"UpdatedBy":775},{"Flag":"INSERT","RoleId":2,"PageId":1005,"UpdatedBy":775},{"Flag":"INSERT","RoleId":2,"PageId":1005,"UpdatedBy":775},{"Flag":"INSERT","RoleId":2,"PageId":1005,"UpdatedBy":775},{"Flag":"INSERT","RoleId":2,"PageId":1005,"UpdatedBy":775}]

-------
If you see All PageId: 1005 its adding last item of loop into array

Comment: export const RolePageMapping = () => {

    const [objRole, setobjRole] = useState({});
    const [lstRole, setlstRole] = useState([]);
    const [lstRolePageMapping, setlstRolePageMapping] = useState([]);
    const [objRolePage, setobjRolePage] = useState({});
    const [lstPage, setlstPage] = useState([]);

Comment: you must use setobjRolePage for change objRolePage value like this =======>>>>> setobjRolePage ({ Flag = "INSERT", RoleId = 2, PageId = data.PageId, UpdatedBy = 775 })